# Will checking "multiple value field" when editing a site column have side effects?

Tags: column, term-store, term-set

SharePoint 2013 non-dev here.

I have a page content type with a column we are using to indicate a location that managed metadata.

I want that field to allow multiple values to be added in from the term set rather than a single entry.

I've managed to find within the page layout area content type > columns > edit > and a check box called 'multiple value field'.

If I check this box - is it going to have some weird flow on to any other areas? Some advice given to me is it will negatively impact search and be "really difficult to allow multiple terms".

I don't come from a dev background, but any advice would be great.